# why can't i retrieve data when i set primary key as text (string)

Tags: c#-4.0, ms-access-2007

```
namespace primarykeycheck
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        OleDbConnection myConn;
        OleDbCommand myComm;
        string queryString;


        public void connectDB()
        {
             myConn = new OleDbConnection(@"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=D:\rummykhan\MCS\Spring 2013\Object Oriented Programming\My Apps\Testing\Database Apps\string as Primary key\primarykeycheck\db.accdb");
        }
        public string fetchName(string ID)
        {
           string Name;
           queryString = "select dbName from mydb where dbID =" + ID;
           myComm = new OleDbCommand(queryString, myConn);
           myConn.Open();
           Name = (string)(myComm.ExecuteScalar()).ToString();
           myConn.Close();
           return Name;
        }
        private void btn_fetch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           connectDB();
           txtName.Text = fetchName(txtID.Text);
        }
```

im working to fetch name when id is given where id data type is string, bt im facing this problem "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"
i've also tried 
Name = (string)myComm.ExecuteScalar();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your statement

```
queryString = "select dbName from mydb where dbID =" + ID;
```

has two problems:

1. It does not put quotes around the `ID` value in the SQL command.
2. It is trying to use the old and **very deprecated** way of building SQL commands. You really should investigate "Parameterized Queries" (there are *lots* of examples here on Stack Overflow) and get familiar with the `.Parameters` property of the `OleDbCommand` object (ref: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.oledb.oledbcommand.parameters.aspx)).